# Angular material cdkDrag drag and drop, how to use target element?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I couldn't find any documentation on how to drag the target element with angular materials "cdkDrag". 
Is there a possibiity to drag the parent element in this case `drag-selector__controls` whenever the material icon is dragged?

This is the current example of dragging the whole element.

```
<div cdkDrag class="drag-selector__controls" >
    <i class="material-icons">
        drag_indicator
    </i>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is something like this

```
<div #containerElement class="drag-selector__controls" >
    <i cdkDrag="containerElement" class="material-icons">
        drag_indicator
    </i>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the user can drag the entire cdkDrag element to move it around. If you want to restrict the user to only be able to do so using a handle element, you can do it by adding the cdkDragHandle directive to an element inside of cdkDrag.

Use `cdkDragHandle`

```
<div cdkDrag class="drag-selector__controls">
    <i class="material-icons" cdkDragHandle>
        drag_indicator
    </i>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/ngdbdrajxqj?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-handle-example.ts

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the same behaviour using the `cdkDragHandle`, [check this example from the Drag and Drop documentation page](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#customizing-the-drag-area-using-a-handle):

```
<div class="example-box" cdkDrag>
  I can only be dragged using the handle

  <div class="example-handle" cdkDragHandle>
    <svg width="24px" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M10 9h4V6h3l-5-5-5 5h3v3zm-1 1H6V7l-5 5 5 5v-3h3v-4zm14 2l-5-5v3h-3v4h3v3l5-5zm-9 3h-4v3H7l5 5 5-5h-3v-3z"></path>
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

They use an SVG to draw the handle icon but you could use a mat-icon element instead.